# Spark: AWSClientIOException in XmlResponsesSaxParser ListBucketHandler while writing parquet to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I have a streaming application in Spark which continuously writes parquet files to S3 location in append mode. Recently it has been failing often with the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on writePath/_temporary/: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerMkdirs(S3AFileSystem.java:1518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.mkdirs(S3AFileSystem.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1961)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:339)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:161)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1545)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1270)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4330)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4277)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4271)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:835)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.listObjects(S3AFileSystem.java:918)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1611)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 5; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:147)
    ... 68 more
```

But I never call the ListBuckets function of S3 explicitly in my code. This error occurs every 1 or 2 days. I also found that recently the number of files written has increased and also the number of deleted markers in the S3 paths have increased significantly (I have versioning enabled). I also tried increasing this timeout value `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.timeout=120000` as suggested here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-to-S3-Error-timeout/td-p/208042 but this didn't help. Versions used:

```
sparkVersion = "2.3.0"
hadoopVersion = "2.8.3"
awsJavaSDKVersion = "1.11.297"
mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: connection to S3 being broken. See [HADOOP-13811](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13811)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening with a versioned bucket where you've deleted a lot (tombeston markers), and you are using a version of the s3a library/AWS SDK combo which uses the v1 list API, which always returns 5000 entries on a long list...the scan can time out if there are lots of tombstone and old versions to skip. Surfaces with XML parser error, e.g. [HADOOP-13811](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13811)

Fix: upgrade spark to the Hadoop-3.1 JARs (everywhere, not just hadoop-aws), and use its (default) v2 listing API. See [HADOOP-13421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13421).

*June 2021 Update*: Hadoop-3.3.1 lets you disable those marker delete calls, `fs.s3a.directory.marker.retention` to `keep`

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.bucket.directory.marker.retention</name>
    <value>keep</value>
  </property>
```

This provides speed and scalability. Spark can also now be built with the hadoop-3.1 JARs.

The marker retention = keep option is not backwards compatible with older branches of Hadoop which do not have a compatibility patch. Check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm not able to understand is, why there are so many delete markers being created in the first place though I'm not explicitly issuing any delete requests from the application. For every file being added, there are 2 directory level delete markers being created. I'm suspecting if i'm hitting this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16090 , though I'm not able to reproduce it by writing a smaller number of files from a dummy application. Also is the fix for the issue to avoid creating spurious delete markers available in any Hadoop 3.x version?

Comment: Update: I was able to reproduce this issue of creating folder level delete markers, by writing small number of files to S3 using s3a path in a dummy app. (previously I used s3 path, which didn't produce these delete markers). I also tried with Hadoop 3.2.1 and there also I'm getting these delete markers. The issue most related this I could find was this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16090 , but I think the fix has not been released yet. @SteveLoughran

Comment: HADOOP-13230 is what you need to wait for. WiP. It's trouble as older releases will get confused reading directories written when the new option is enabled...they'll mistake a dir marker for an empty dir